# Mapping URL to more than one action in Interaction Studio

Tags: interaction-studio

We have multiple URL's mapped to a single action in Interaction Studio. We would also like to map those URL's to individual actions. The documentation is dated but it seems like there used to be a way to map an action to a page title instead of a URL which might have been a workaround.

https://doc.evergage.com/display/EKB/Create+or+Remove+an+Action+Mapping

Actions can no longer be found under settings on the dashboard. So, those instructions are not useful.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!